# LaTeX - интервал между абзацами

Tags: latex

Хочу что бы между абзацами был интервал. Хоть какой!

Документ начинается с:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
```

При этом отступ первой строки абзаца делается, а вот интервал между абзацами - нет. Задавать величину отступа пытался по разному:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
```

Эти команды пытался вставлять и в преамбуле и в основном тексте - ничего не помогает!

В чём может быть дело?

Добавляю минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \title{Теория глупости}
    \author{Карло Чиполла}
    \date{\today}

\abstract{Когда я был юнцом, мой папа уже совершил удивительное открытие - он обнаружил, что руководство той страны, где мы жили тогда, неявно использует тайные для народа знания, которые он систематизировал и назвал Теорией глупости. А подтолкнула меня к воспоминаниям статья западного автора}

\section{ТЕОРИЯ ГЛУПОСТИ}

Итальянский историк-экономист Карло Чиполла долгие годы исследовал феномен человеческой глупости и подошел к этому вопросу весьма основательно. В результате ученый сформулировал 5 универсальных законов, работающих в любом обществе. При этом оказалось, что глупость сама по себе намного опаснее, чем мы привыкли о ней думать.


\textbf{Первый закон глупости:} Человек всегда недооценивает количество идиотов, которые его окружают.
На первый взгляд это утверждение звучит банально и с оттенком снобизма. однако жизнь доказывает его истинность. Судите сами: как бы вы ни оценивали людей, вы постоянно будете сталкиваться со следующими ситуациями:
- человек, который всегда выглядел умным и рациональным, оказывается невероятным идиотом;
- глупцы все время возникают в самых неожиданных местах в самое неподходящее время, чтобы разрушить ваши планы.

\textbf{Второй закон глупости:} Вероятность того, что человек глуп, не зависит от других его качеств.
Карло Чиполла пришел к выводу, что глупость, как качество личности, закладывается природой, также, как цвет волос или группа крови. Человек таким рождается. А воспитание и образование не имеют ничего общего с вероятностью наличия определенного числа глупцов в обществе. Это подтвердили многочисленные эксперименты в университетах над пятью группами: студентами, офисными служащими, обслуживающим персоналом, сотрудниками администрации и преподавателями. Вот что пишет сам ученый. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Проблему воспроизвести не удалось. У меня на TeXLive под MSWindows работают все представленные варианты для `\parskip` (и в преамбуле, и в тексте). Может, в документе используются какие-то пакеты, которые переопределяют этот промежуток?.. Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный пример, где эта проблема воспроизводится. (а вот `\parindent` получается изменять, только когда он задается ниже пакета `babel`.)

Comment: @Vladimir Изменил текст вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в команде `\abstract`. Я не стал искать, где именно она определяется и что у нее внутри, но её точно нет у меня в классе *article*. Если ее заменить на окружение `abstract`, которое определено в *article*, то всё начинает работать нормально.

(как вариант, можно задание отступов сделать после команды `\abstract`, тогда тоже всё будет работать правильно)

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{5ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{awesomebox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \title{Теория глупости}
    \author{Карло Чиполла}
    \date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
Когда я был юнцом, мой папа уже совершил удивительное открытие - он обнаружил, что руководство той страны, где мы жили тогда, неявно использует тайные для народа знания, которые он систематизировал и назвал Теорией глупости. А подтолкнула меня к воспоминаниям статья западного автора
\end{abstract}

\section{ТЕОРИЯ ГЛУПОСТИ}

Итальянский историк-экономист Карло Чиполла долгие годы исследовал феномен человеческой глупости и подошел к этому вопросу весьма основательно. В результате ученый сформулировал 5 универсальных законов, работающих в любом обществе. При этом оказалось, что глупость сама по себе намного опаснее, чем мы привыкли о ней думать.

\textbf{Первый закон глупости:} Человек всегда недооценивает количество идиотов, которые его окружают.
На первый взгляд это утверждение звучит банально и с оттенком снобизма. однако жизнь доказывает его истинность. Судите сами: как бы вы ни оценивали людей, вы постоянно будете сталкиваться со следующими ситуациями:
- человек, который всегда выглядел умным и рациональным, оказывается невероятным идиотом;
- глупцы все время возникают в самых неожиданных местах в самое неподходящее время, чтобы разрушить ваши планы.

\textbf{Второй закон глупости:} Вероятность того, что человек глуп, не зависит от других его качеств.
Карло Чиполла пришел к выводу, что глупость, как качество личности, закладывается природой, также, как цвет волос или группа крови. Человек таким рождается. А воспитание и образование не имеют ничего общего с вероятностью наличия определенного числа глупцов в обществе. Это подтвердили многочисленные эксперименты в университетах над пятью группами: студентами, офисными служащими, обслуживающим персоналом, сотрудниками администрации и преподавателями. Вот что пишет сам ученый. 
\end{document}
```

PS: я проверял на miktex, но думаю, в TeXLive это тоже должно тоже сработать.  Вечером могу проерить и в TeXLive.
А еще я на всякий случай добавил пакет `indentfirst`, который ставит абзацный отступ в первом абзаце раздела (это нужно в miktex, про TeXLive - не помню).

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Заменил команду на окружение и промежутки между абзацами появились! А я уже себе плешь прочесал - никогда бы не подумал на *\abstrakt* ! Осталась, правда, одна закавыка :-)   Промежутки появились в основном тексте документа. А вот в окружениях типа *minipage* или *verse* - нет...  Странно это!

Comment: @Sergey, рад был помочь :-). Что касается *minipage* и *verse* - они, скорее всего, переопределяют эти параметры (правда, про последнего я не уверен - он может использовать для отступов и вообще другую командную длину - тогда ее можно найти и задать отдельно). Я это к тому, что можно попробовать переопределять отступы внутри окружений. А если это делать лень (если надо использовать много таких окружений), то наверное, проще определить свои окружения с нужными параметрами.

Comment: -"Что касается minipage и verse" - Вы оказались совершенно правы! В *minipage* это помогло, а вот в *verse* - нет. Буду разбираться. Ещё раз - спасибо!